# Erlang MQTT configuration broken?

Tags: mqtt, iot, broker, emq

There is a way (according to [this](http://emqttd-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html) and [this](https://github.com/emqtt/emq-auth-username)) in Erlang eMQ to enable in my MQTT Broker a plugin for the **emq_auth_username**, meaning I can config my broker to allow connections bases on my **etc/emq_auth_username.conf** file.

I did create the file and put inside similar entries...

however myclient is not comming in:

[image]

my file looks like:

> ### auth.user.$N.username = admin
>
> ### auth.user.$N.password = public
>
> ### auth.user.$1.username = dummy_username
>
> ### auth.user.$1.password = dummy_password
>
> ### auth.user.$N.username = dummy_username
>
> ### auth.user.$N.password = dummy_password

since am trying to get how it works....

any hint how can  I add a new credential here in this file???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually need something like this...

```
auth.user.1.username=fred
auth.user.1.password=bl0665
auth.user.2.username=jane
auth.user.2.password=j4n3
auth.user.3.username=...
...etc..
```